# Entitlements Related List in VF

Tags: visualforce

I have created a VF page which replaces the Account View page.  I have replaced the  areas, but for some reason "Entitlements" is not limited to the current account.  It shows *all* system-wide entitlements, not just the current account.  It is not set up any different than other relatedLists:

```
<apex:relatedList list="Cases" pageSize="1000"/>
<apex:relatedList list="Entitlements" pageSize="1000"/>
<apex:relatedList list="Contacts" pageSize="1000"/>
<apex:relatedList list="AccountContactRoles" pageSize="1000"/>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me, I've even tried using the 'subject' attribute...

```
<apex:relatedList list="Entitlements" pageSize="1000" subject="{!Account.Id}"/>
```

Which is described in the [apex:relatedList](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm) help as...

> The parent record from which the data and related list definition are derived. If not specified, and if using a standard controller, this value is automatically set to the value of the ID query string parameter in the page URL.

Which just not seem to be happening at all, either way.

I'd raise this as a bug with Salesforce.